# angularjs form ignors non form fields on submit

Tags: angularjs, forms

i am using angularjs' form stuff to gather user information. to get time i user [`<timpicker>`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) it seems that this field is not set (ng-model of timepicker is null) if i call my `ng-submit="submit()"`.

The only way i found so far is to call ng-change in timepicker and set a viable in scope which is then used in submit. Beside the fact that this is ugly, the main problem is if the user doesn't change the value (default is now) i don't have a time.

Is there a way to gather all ng-model variables in $scope on form's "ng-submit"?

**EDIT** It is not a problem of form its [problem of timepicker](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1114). As soon as i change the time once the model gets filled (without the need of change method)

Answer (score 1):

It will gather all ng-model variables on $scope that are set on input fields within the form. If you want to add a variable to your form without actually showing it on the screen, you can do:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="yourVariable" />
```

Comment: do you mean <timetracker ng-model="time"/> ...<input type="hidden" ng-model="time" /> or do i need some {{}}. when will "time" be read and written to another field?

Comment: Basicly what you describe should do the trick! How are you submitting your form?

Comment: with ng-submit="submit()", a submit() function and a normal submit button

Comment: I usually use an object for my form, so basicly you would have like: `$scope.form = {}` and then in your form like: `<input type="hidden" ng-model="form.time" />` and then on my submit: `ng-submit(form)` That also makes debugging a lot more easy, since you can start out with just `console.log(form)` and see what values are submitted.

Comment: i just found this: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1114 (its not a problem with form but with timepicker) - thanks for the last hint.